# Conditional Formatting background color in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to color the background of any rows that have a Date populated. For example:
If Date A is populated, then turn the row gray
If Date A is not populated, then leave the row white

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color in the properties of the row to an expression.

`=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!DateA.value), "White", "Gray")`